# post data to influx database

Tags: java, database, logging, influxdb

I have logs in the form of string. I want to send these logs form my application to influx Database. So, i have written these functions.

```
private String formatAsJsonArrayString(List<String> logs) {
            Gson gson = new Gson();
            return gson.toJson(logs);
        }

public void startFlushToInfluxDbThread() {
    Thread flushToInfluxDbThread = new Thread(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            while (true) {
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(influxPostWaitTime);
                    List<String> logs = extractNEntries(queue, 1000);
                    String dataToPost = formatAsJsonArrayString(logs);
                    postToInfluxDB(dataToPost);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }

        }
```

but now i am unable to think how to write postToInfluxDB() function. Can somebody guide me to do this? I mean to say, how connection will be made and all that related stuff.

Comment: Is there a specific reason why you are not using the official java library at https://github.com/influxdb/influxdb-java?